# How to change Option Menu Style

Tags: android

I already done my Option Menu but it's show like a List View but I need style like Button rectangle.

My Option Menu
[image]

I need Option Menu Like this
[image]

How To change option menu style?

Regards,

Comment: The old option menu is discouraged after the release of API level 14, you shouldn't try to mock or use the old options menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            CambiarFondoMenuInflater();
           return Menus.CrearMenus(contexto,menu, TipoMenu.PRINCIPAL);
        }
```

CambiarFondoMenuInflater() method:

```
protected void CambiarFondoMenuInflater()
    {
        final LayoutInflater infl = getLayoutInflater();

        infl.setFactory(new Factory()
        {
            public View onCreateView(final String name, 
                                     final Context context,
                                     final AttributeSet attrs)
            {
                if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView"))
                    return null; 
                View view = null;

                if (IconMenuItemView_class == null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IconMenuItemView_class = getClassLoader().loadClass(name);
                    }
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                    {

                        return null;
                    }
                }
                if (IconMenuItemView_class == null)
                    return null;

                if (IconMenuItemView_constructor == null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IconMenuItemView_constructor = 
                        IconMenuItemView_class.getConstructor(standard_inflater_constructor_signature);
                    }
                    catch (SecurityException e)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                if (IconMenuItemView_constructor == null)
                    return null; 

                try
                {
                    Object[] args = new Object[] { context, attrs };
                    view = (View)(IconMenuItemView_constructor.newInstance(args));
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
                {
                    return null; 
                }
                catch (InstantiationException e)
                {
                    return null; 
                }
                catch (IllegalAccessException e)
                {
                    return null; 
                }
                catch (InvocationTargetException e)
                {
                    return null; 
                }
                if (null == view) 
                    return null; 


                final View v = view;
                new Handler().post(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                        try
                        {
                           // Here you can change whatever you want :)
                            TextView tv = (TextView)v;
                            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                        catch (ClassCastException e)
                        {
                            // Don't set TextView attributes
                        }
                    }
                });

                return view;
            }
        });
    }
```

This information is taken from a post on this website. I've searched it but I can't find it, so I let my code here. If anyone can reference it I'd appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the folders values-v11 , values-v14 etc.,
Dont delete the default values folder.