# How to change Option Menu Item layout?

Tags: android, xml, menuitem, optionmenu

How to customize the Option Menu item layout from xml or programmatically.
I found many question but no good answer yet.

[How to change Option Menu Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899199/how-to-change-option-menu-style)

[How to change layout by clicking items of menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676807/how-to-change-layout-by-clicking-items-of-menu)

[How to change Menu Item Color & Size programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591164/how-to-change-menu-item-color-size-programmatically)

Comment: What do you want, do you want to inflate a layout on option menu click ?

Comment: The default appearance of the option menu does not fit with theme(colors) of my application.

Answer (score 1):

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/itemId"
    android:title="Item title"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_layout" />
```

Note that this layout will be shown **only in the ActionBar**. If the item is in the overflow menu only title will be shown.